# How to save custom accidentals after shut down Guitar Pro 7

Tags: accidentals, guitar-pro

My pentagram looks fine in Guitar Pro 7 but after I save my `.gp` file and close it something went wrong when I reopen it. I find flat accidentals changed by sharps (e.g., **Gb** is replaced by **F#**).

For example, a bar like this one:

[image: bar before shut down with flat accidentals]

is going to be replaced after open the file again by its analogous:

[image: bar after shut down with when flats changed]

Is there a way to force Guitar Pro to save the user input as it was written originally?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Maybe you should submit a support request https://support.guitar-pro.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems to be a question to be addressed by the producer of the product.